# Need help digesting JSON blob returned using express-handlebars node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm getting started with node.js and am working through a tutorial that pings the Accuweather API and returns a JSON blob of data.

I've ALMOST got it ... but the display piece is what's holding me back:

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/:city', (req, res) => {
  rp({
      uri: 'http://apidev.accuweather.com/locations/v1/search',
      qs: {
    q: req.params.city,
    apiKey: 'hoArfRosT1215'
      // Use your accuweather API key here
  },
  json: true
})
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  res.render('home', data)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
  res.render('error')
})
})

app.listen(3000)
```

home.hbs

```
  <h2>Success!</h2>
  <h2>{{data}}</h2>`
```

error.hbs

```
 <h2>Error<h2>
```

home.hbs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Express handlebars</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

I've Googled and haven't really found a great solution. I've looked into handlebars helped functions ... but didn't really come up with anything.

How would I start to display some of the 'data' chunk coming back from the Accuweather API?

FYI here's there JSON blog that comes back I got from console.logging it

```
[ { Version: 1,
    Key: '2156696',
    Type: 'City',
    Rank: 385,
    LocalizedName: 'Providence Forge',
    EnglishName: 'Providence Forge',
    PrimaryPostalCode: '19468',
    Region: 
     { ID: 'NAM',
       LocalizedName: 'North America',
       EnglishName: 'North America' },
    Country: 
     { ID: 'US',
       LocalizedName: 'United States',
       EnglishName: 'United States' },
    AdministrativeArea: 
     { ID: 'PA',
       LocalizedName: 'Pennsylvania',
       EnglishName: 'Pennsylvania',
       Level: 1,
       LocalizedType: 'State',
       EnglishType: 'State',
       CountryID: 'US' },
    TimeZone: 
     { Code: 'EST',
       Name: 'America/New_York',
       GmtOffset: -5,
       IsDaylightSaving: false,
       NextOffsetChange: '2017-03-12T07:00:00Z' },
    GeoPosition: { Latitude: 40.18, Longitude: -75.523, Elevation: [Object] },
    IsAlias: false,
    SupplementalAdminAreas: [ [Object] ],
    DataSets: [ 'Alerts', 'ForecastConfidence', 'MinuteCast' ] },
  { Version: 1,
    Key: '2172276',
    Type: 'City',
    Rank: 385,
    LocalizedName: 'Providence Forge',
    EnglishName: 'Providence Forge',
    PrimaryPostalCode: '23140',
    Region: 
     { ID: 'NAM',
       LocalizedName: 'North America',
       EnglishName: 'North America' },
    Country: 
     { ID: 'US',
       LocalizedName: 'United States',
       EnglishName: 'United States' },
    AdministrativeArea: 
     { ID: 'VA',
       LocalizedName: 'Virginia',
       EnglishName: 'Virginia',
       Level: 1,
       LocalizedType: 'State',
       EnglishType: 'State',
       CountryID: 'US' },
    TimeZone: 
     { Code: 'EST',
       Name: 'America/New_York',
       GmtOffset: -5,
       IsDaylightSaving: false,
       NextOffsetChange: '2017-03-12T07:00:00Z' },
    GeoPosition: { Latitude: 37.442, Longitude: -77.044, Elevation: [Object] },
    IsAlias: false,
    SupplementalAdminAreas: [ [Object] ],
    DataSets: [ 'Alerts', 'ForecastConfidence', 'MinuteCast' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass variables to views is as attributes of the second object parameter, so change this:

```
res.render('home', data);
```

To this:

```
res.render('home', {data: data});
```

[Source](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render).

As for displaying the data, you can iterate over the JSON array and display it in `home.hbs` like this:

```
<h2>Success!</h2>
<ul>
  {{#each data}}
    <li>
      Name: {{this.EnglishName}}<br>
      Region: {{this.Region.EnglishName}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

More info about the `each` helper can be found on [this page](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have as:

```
 res.render('home', data)
```

I believe it should be:

```
res.render("home", {data:data})
```

as for your html

```
  {{#each data}}
   <div>
      Name: {{this.LocalizedName}}
      Rank: {{this.Rank}}
   </div>
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! https://github.com/jaybird1905/nodejstest That's my repo. I'm now getting this when I go to localhost:
Error: Missing helper: "this.Rank:"
   at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: @JayAigner Thats cause in your home.hbs file, you have "   Rank: {{this.Rank: 385}}" .  I needs to be just  Rank: {{this.Rank}}

Comment: @JayAigner I also submitted the change to your repo.  You can merge it and pull it down, or just fix the line yourself.  Also if this solves your problem please click the check mark